# Is Type[type] the correct type hint for a class object?

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-3.5, type-hinting

My question: is my usage of `AnyType` (as I have defined it below) correct? The goal is for `AnyType` to accept any class object, but instances of class objects, or function types, or other things that aren't of type `type`, should be rejected.

Details:

I have a class that looks something like this:

```
MixinSubclsType = Type["ChildRegistryMixin"]
AnyType = Type[type] # <- is this correct?

class ChildRegistryMixin:
    """Mixin class that creates classes which track subclasses.

    Each new child class will track its own children."""
    _subclasses: Dict[Any, MixinSubclsType] = dict()
    _make_reg_key: Callable[[AnyType], Any]] = lambda subcls: getattr(subcls, "__name__")
    def __init_subclass__(subcls,
                          make_reg_key: Optional[Callable[[AnyType], Any]]] = None,
                          **kwargs) -> None:
        # implementation here
```

Is `Type[type]` the correct way to tell the type checker the `lambda` is supposed to only accept class objects?

---

Since more information is sometimes better than less, below is the entire implementation.

```
class ChildRegistryMixin:
    """Mixin class that creates classes which track subclasses.

    Each new child class will track its own children.

    Usage example 1:

        class RegisteredByName(ChildRegistryMixin): ...

        assert ChildRegistryMixin._subclasses["RegisteredByName"] is RegisteredByName

    Usage example 2:

        valid_lookup = dict(ClassName="othername")

        class RegisteredByPop(ChildRegistryMixin,
                              make_reg_key=lambda subcls:
                                           valid_lookup.pop(subcls.__name__)):
            pass

        class ClassName(RegisteredByPop): ...

        assert RegisteredByPop._subclasses["othername"] is ClassName

        class InvalidName(RegisteredByPop): ... # <-- ERROR!

    """
    _subclasses: Dict[Any, MixinSubclsType] = dict()
    _make_reg_key: Callable([AnyType], Any) = lambda subcls: getattr(subcls, "__name__")
    def __init_subclass__(subcls,
                          make_reg_key: Optional[Callable([AnyType], Any)] = None,
                          **kwargs) -> None:
        super().__init_subclass__(**kwargs)
        # for later child classes of the new class
        subcls._subclasses = dict()
        # child added to the reg of closest parent that is a subclass of CRB
        for parent_cls in subcls.mro()[1:]:
            if issubclass(parent_cls, ChildRegistryMixin):
                break
        else:
            parent_cls = ChildRegistryMixin
        # make the key
        key = parent_cls._make_reg_key(subcls)
        # can't have multiple child classes with same key
        if key not in parent_cls._subclasses:
            parent_cls._subclasses[key] = subcls
        else:
            raise ChildRegistryError(f"Attempted to overwrite the "
                                     f"child class key {key!r} in the "
                                     f"{parent_cls.__name__} registry")
        # inherit the subclass' key maker from parent if one was not provided
        subcls._make_reg_key = parent_cls._make_reg_key if make_reg_key is None\
                                                        else make_reg_key
```

Comment: I would use `Type[object]`, because `Type[type]` looks like a metaclass. But then I would define `Type[object]` to be the same as `type`, so I would use just simply `type`.

Comment: Good point! I understand the semantic difference; someone looking at the code would reasonably think "metaclass!" when seeing `Type[type]`. Functionally, aren't `Type[object]` and `Type[type]` equivalent?

Comment: @MegaIng I would also suggest, though, that `type` also sort of looks like "metaclass" as well to a reader. So maybe the semantics of `Type[object]` are superior. But I'll have to think about it.

Comment: @RickTeachey `x: Type[foo]` is basically an annotation indicating that `isxinstance(x, foo)` must be true. `Type[object]` is a type covering *everything*, since `object` is the root of the class hierarchy. `Type[type]` only covers class objects.

Comment: @chepner is that correct? My understanding is `object` itself covers *everything*. But `Type[object]` would only cover class objects, since the type of `object` is `type`... need to find an easy way to figure this out in a type checker. `x: Type[foo]` says that `issubclass(x, foo)` is true, not `isinstance`. `x:foo` says `isinstance(x,foo)` is true.

Comment: Right; the documentation for `Type` sums it up nicely: "`Type[Any]` is equivalent to `Type` which in turn is equivalent to `type`, which is the root of Python’s metaclass hierarchy." (And the metaclass hierarchy is a *subtree* in the class hierarchy, whose root is `object`.)

Comment: @chepner Ok so `Type[object]` matches against *the `object` class itself* and its child classes, which of course includes ANY class object (including metaclasses since `issubclass(MyMeta, object)` is true), but NOT instances of those classes, functions, etc? So `Type[object]` seems like what I'm wanting here.